# Is there a way to calculate a streak in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of goals scored by Messi and Ronaldo and would like to calculate scoring streaks.

The table is set up as follows

```
Game | Opponenet  | Goals scored
--------------------------------
1    | Barcelona  |  0  
2    | Atletico M |  1  
3    | Sevilla    |  2  
4    | Villareal  |  3  
5    | Xerez      |  0
```

The formula will calculate that the streak lasted for 3 games and the total goals scored in the streak was 6.

Comment: Do you want to calculate a streak for games against any opponent or only against the same team?

Comment: against any opponent have edited question.

Comment: Can you explain where you would want to see the results? Especially in a bigger data sample with more than one streak, can you mock up manually what you would like to see where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these formulas in cells D2, E2 and F2 respectively and copy down

=IF(C2>0,C2+D1,0)
=IF(C2>0,E1+1,0)
=IF(AND(D2>D1,D3=0),"Streak of "&E2&" games with "&D2&" goals total","")

Hide columns D and E if desired.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I whipped up an [Excel spreadsheet (Google Docs)](http://bit.ly/JpnWIX) with the formulas you need, you can adapt them to your existing spreadsheet. The worksheet has 4 columns (see the link for the actual formulas):

**Score** is the score of the game
**Streak Test** is TRUE when **Score** = 0
**Streak Value** adds 1 per non-zero game and resets when **Score** = 0
**Streak Total** cumulatively adds the **Score** of each game and resets when **Score** = 0

```
Score   StreakTest  StreakValue StreakTotal
5       FALSE       1           5
0       TRUE        0           0
3       FALSE       1           3
2       FALSE       2           5
4       FALSE       3           9
2       FALSE       4           11
0       TRUE        0           0
3       FALSE       1           3
0       TRUE        0           0
2       FALSE       1           2
4       FALSE       2           6
2       FALSE       3           8
3       FALSE       4           11
4       FALSE       5           15
0       TRUE        0           0
```

If you wanted to for aesthetics, you can always hide the **StreakTest** column in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please edit your post to include the formulas you used. It's safe to say most people navigating to this page with similar problems will not be willing to download a workbook to get help.